# awk get the data based on if else condition

Tags: linux, if-statement, awk

I need again your expertise, I am trying to do some conditional using awk to get the columns.

If I look at the `$5` the data can have `year` and in some places a `date`.

So when `year` is there it's good to print, but other values where I have `date and time` like `05:17:27` then I need to print the last field.

```
2021
2021
05:17:27
20:33:17
05:17:20
2020
2020
2021
2020
2021
```

Below is my sample data.

### data_file.

```
yogutdb01   Mon 28 Jun 2021 11:19:56 PM MST
yogutdb02   Thu 30 Sep 2021 02:02:53 AM MST
yogutdb03   Thu Jul 13 05:17:27 2017
yogutdb04   Fri Jun 23 20:33:17 2017
yogutdb05   Thu Jul 13 05:17:20 2017
yogutdb06   Wed 24 Jun 2020 03:49:16 PM MST
yogutdb07   Wed 24 Jun 2020 04:05:10 PM MST
yogutdb08   Sat 22 May 2021 04:19:14 AM MST
yogutdb09   Thu 09 Apr 2020 12:16:32 PM CEST
yogutdb10   Tue 11 May 2021 03:03:02 PM MST
```

### My trial:   I am using below but getting syntax error on the `else` condition.

```
$ awk '{ ($5=="[^0-9]+$")print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5; else print  $1,$2,$3,$4,$NF}' my_data.text
```

### Desired Should be:

```
yogutdb01   2021 
yogutdb02   2021
yogutdb03   2017
yogutdb04   2017    
yogutdb05   2017
yogutdb06   2020
yogutdb07   2020
yogutdb08   2021
yogutdb09   2020
yogutdb10   2021
```

**OR**

```
yogutdb01   Mon 28 Jun 2021
yogutdb02   Thu 30 Sep 2021
yogutdb03   Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb04   Fri Jun 23 2017
yogutdb05   Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb06   Wed 24 Jun 2020 
yogutdb07   Wed 24 Jun 2020 
yogutdb08   Sat 22 May 2021 
yogutdb09   Thu 09 Apr 2020 
yogutdb10   Tue 11 May 2021
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please do mention what is the logic of getting expected output in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13,  thanks for looking , i have just updated by post, thnx again as usual

Comment: In your desired output (updated one), the order of day and month looks inconsistent. Which is your preferable one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You cannot use the `==` operator to test the regex match. Instead you can use
  `match()` function or `~` operator.
- You should place the `^` regex in front of `[0-9]`, not inside.

Then would you please try:

```
awk '{if (match($5,/^[0-9]+$/)) print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; else print $1, $2, $3, $4, $NF}' my_data.text
```

Output:

```
yogutdb01 Mon 28 Jun 2021
yogutdb02 Thu 30 Sep 2021
yogutdb03 Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb04 Fri Jun 23 2017
yogutdb05 Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb06 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb07 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb08 Sat 22 May 2021
yogutdb09 Thu 09 Apr 2020
yogutdb10 Tue 11 May 2021
```

Here is an alternative using `~` operator:

```
awk '$5 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; next} {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $NF}' my_data.text
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your desired outcome, you should try below which will work.

You can use Regular expression matches like `~`.

```
$ awk '{ if ($5 !~ /:/) { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5; next } { print $1,$2,$3,$4, $NF } }'   exampl_data1
```

### Result:

```
yogutdb01 Mon 28 Jun 2021
yogutdb02 Thu 30 Sep 2021
yogutdb03 Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb04 Fri Jun 23 2017
yogutdb05 Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb06 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb07 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb08 Sat 22 May 2021
yogutdb09 Thu 09 Apr 2020
yogutdb10 Tue 11 May 2021
```

Just to mention, as @tshiono also asked in the comment,to get the output in order, you can use below.

```
$ awk '{ if ($5 !~ /:/) { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; next } { print $1, $2, $4, $3, $NF } }'   exampl_data1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could print the first 4 fields, and check the 5th field for only 4 digits.  If there are not only 4 digits, print the last field.

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, ($5 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? $5 : $NF)}' my_data.text
```

Output

```
yogutdb01 Mon 28 Jun 2021
yogutdb02 Thu 30 Sep 2021
yogutdb03 Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb04 Fri Jun 23 2017
yogutdb05 Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb06 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb07 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb08 Sat 22 May 2021
yogutdb09 Thu 09 Apr 2020
yogutdb10 Tue 11 May 2021
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE : new version that also fixes month-date cross-placements in columns 3 and 4 :

```
 echo "${aaaaa}" \
  \
  | mawk 'NF=_+!($_=$(!+$NF?_:NF))*($3=$(2+2^(\
                 __= $4 ~ /^[0-3][0-9]$/))     \
                    substr("",$4=$(4-__)))'     \_=5 
 
yogutdb01 Mon 28 Jun 2021
yogutdb02 Thu 30 Sep 2021
yogutdb03 Thu 13 Jul 2017 *** fixed these 3 rows
yogutdb04 Fri 23 Jun 2017 ***
yogutdb05 Thu 13 Jul 2017 ***
yogutdb06 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb07 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb08 Sat 22 May 2021
yogutdb09 Thu 09 Apr 2020
yogutdb10 Tue 11 May 2021
```

first one acts upon the assumption that there aren't any numerical data at `$NF` other than 4-digit year

2nd option performs a more thorough year-data check. Both involve assigning the proper year value into `$5`, then using assignment into `NF` to trim out all the excess columns/fields to the right of it.

```
 < datafile.txt \
 \
 | mawk 'NF=_^($_=$(!+$NF?_:NF))^!_' \_=5

   or 

 | mawk 'NF= +_+($_=$(/[ ][012][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/? NF :_))*!_' \_=5
 | gawk 'NF= _+!($_=$(/[ ][0-2][0-9]{3}$/       ? NF :_))'    \_=5


yogutdb01 Mon 28 Jun 2021
yogutdb02 Thu 30 Sep 2021
yogutdb03 Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb04 Fri Jun 23 2017
yogutdb05 Thu Jul 13 2017
yogutdb06 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb07 Wed 24 Jun 2020
yogutdb08 Sat 22 May 2021
yogutdb09 Thu 09 Apr 2020
yogutdb10 Tue 11 May 2021
```